# Request failed due to an error: (http_request_fail

Tags: import, xml

I uploaded the XML file to get back up information such as posts, pages, and media files. either media files, everything came.

but for the media files, WordPress gives an error.as a note, the media files have related to the posts and some plugin content.

a full error message is Turkish so sorry:

İçeri aktarma başarısız Ortam `“1”`: Request failed due to an error: Geçerli bir adres sağlanmadı. (`http_request_failed`)

I am giving the XML file:

I am good at wp theme and plugin development.SO, is there any coding solution?

Are the image files in the XML file in the correct way?

https://gofile.io/d/gxXjD7

thanks

Comment: What does the error message say in english? Is this your browser giving you the error or WP? Google translate suggests it says a valid address was not provided. Is this the standard WordPress import/export functionality?

Comment: @TomJNowell yes, standart wp importer also google translate says correctly what it says in Turkish.yes, wp gives the error

Comment: @TomJNowell Do you have solution suggestion?

Comment: I don't, I was just asking a clarifying question. If I have a solution I'll post it as an answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a writen links in the xml files, image files such as the files which ends with .jpg extention, were hosted in my ex-hosting.So, now, the image files dont exist now.

You can search jpg word in xml files, and you will see links.So, this is a proof what I said above paragraph.

So, also the only solution was manually upload again so I solved my problem by hand.